# Android DES decryption ECB mode

Tags: android, encryption, des

I am trying to dectypt data,
which was encrypted with mcrypt
DES, ECB mode
and then wrapped into Base64.
Here is my code:

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
// ...

// Crypted input data and the key
String criptedInput = "vsm1/sLWAUxW7JjKT/Amww==";
final String KEY = "jf7746yghndd";

// Decoding base64
byte[] bytesDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(criptedInput.getBytes());

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), "DES");

Cipher cipher = null;
String result = null;

try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

    // Initialize the cipher for decryption
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    // Decrypt the text
    byte[] textDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytesDecoded);

    result = new String(textDecrypted);

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (BadPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I am catching java.security.invalidkeyexception: des key too long - should be 8 bytes..

What is wrong?

Comment: Using DES in ECB mode is not secure, it used a 56-bit key and ECB is not a secure mode. You need to push back against this or you are part of creating the growing security problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DES supports only a key size of 56 bit (64 bit with parity). So you cannot use a larger key with it. Mcrypt knows this and silently only uses the first 8 bytes. Mcrypt also doesn't implement proper padding. Instead it pads with 0x00 bytes. You should be able to use a similar, but not same, padding in BouncyCastle:

```
Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/ZeroBytePadding", "BC");
```

---

**Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In this case I have to use ECB as it is provided by the other side. Unfortunately, with your code I am catching: "javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException: Padding ZeroPadding unknown"

Comment: It might be ZeroBytePadding

Comment: Yeah, ZeroBytePadding  is OK, but I am again catching java.security.invalidkeyexception: des key too long - should be 8 bytes

Comment: As I said, use only the first 8 bytes of the key.

Comment: You could use a shorter key: `KEY = "jf7746yg";` or use only the first 8 bytes when creating the keyspec: `new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes('UTF-8'), 0, 8, "DES");`